# constrained optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Consider a firm with two inputs K and L that produce an output Q(K,
>   L). The firm’s cost function is C(K, L) = K + 2L. It is required to
>   minimize C(K, L) subject to the constraint Q(K, L) = q where q is a
>   positive real constant. You may assume that the optimization problem
>   has a solution at an interior point of R2+.
>
> ```
>         (i) Show that
> ```
>
> $ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial L} =  2\frac{\partial Q}{\partial K}$ holds at the optimal point.
>
> ```
>        (ii) Assume that Q(K,L) is homogeneous of degree m. At the optimal point, also
> ```
>
> assume that  ∂Q/∂K = r
>
> for some positive real r. Find the constrained minimum value of C(K,
>   L) in terms of m,r and q.

I am not sure how to do this problem or where to start?

would the set up be something like,

$ L( c, \lambda) = K + 2L + \lambda q$

$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L} = 2 $

$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial K} = 1$

$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial \lambda} = q $

how would I find the constrained minimum value  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ F = K + 2L + \lambda (Q  - q) $

$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial K} = 1 + \lambda \frac{\partial Q}{\partial K} = 0 $

$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial L} = 2 + \lambda \frac{\partial Q}{\partial L} = 0 $

So, (i) is true and $ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial L} = 2r $

Using (ii), Euler's Theorem states that

$ K\frac{\partial Q}{\partial K} + L\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L} = mQ $

So, $ Kr + 2Lr = mq $

Then, $ C(K,L) = K + 2L = mq/r $.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, however can you please explain why it is $ \lambda(Q-q) $ ? I dont understand this part?

Comment: It makes no difference if you use $ \lambda (Q-q) $ or $ \lambda Q$. Some authors would use $ \lambda (Q-q) $ where $ Q-q=0 $ is the constraint. They would then have $  \frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = 0 $ and might also calculate $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} $.

Comment: Hi thank you for clarifying! Just one more clear up if you don’t mind. Why does $ df/dL = 1 + \lambda dQ\dK $ ?? I don’t understand this part

Comment: Just edited the answer.